# json の int 配列の中身を java 言語上の int 型で取得したい

Tags: java

以下のようなテストコードをかいて

```
import java.io.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("test.json");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject)parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
        JSONArray data1 = (JSONArray)json.get("data1");
        System.out.println(sum(data1));
        JSONArray data2 = (JSONArray)json.get("data2");
        System.out.println(sum(data2));
    }

    private static int sum(JSONArray ja) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ja.size(); i++)
            sum += ((Integer)ja.get(i)).intValue();
        return sum;
    }
}
```

このようなJSONを読み込ませてみたところ

```
{
    "data1": [1,2,3,4],
    "data2": [11,12,13,14]
}
```

以下のキャストエラーが出ます
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/wikis/DecodingExamples.wiki
こちら公式ページにデコードサンプルが載ってるんですが
全部 System.out.print してしまっているので
JsonArray#get した型を何にキャストすれば int になるのかよくわかりません

java で JSON を扱うのに同じ名前の JsonArray ってのがあるみたいなんですが
たまたま最初にみたのが simple だったのでこっち使ってしまいましたが
もう１つの JsonArray の方が使いやすいんでしょうか…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum += ((Integer)ja.get(i)).intValue();`を`System.out.println(ja.get(i).getClass().getName());`に書き換えると、`java.lang.Long`が返ることが分かります。
`ja.get(i)`からは表面上Object型が返ってきますが、中身はLong型ですので、下記の記述でキャストすれば正常に動きます。

```
sum += ((Long)ja.get(i)).intValue();
```

なお、類似質問は本家SOにもありますが、Integer型ではなくLong型が返ってくる理由は見当たりませんでした。

[JSON - simple get an Integer instead of Long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20869138)
[JSON Simple: integer parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29770329)

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`Long`は`Integer`にキャスト不能ですので、

```
sum += ((Long)ja.get(i)).intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

[こちらの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/90998/2808)に記載したとおり、現在の実装上、整数値は`Long`型で解決されますが、このあたり([1](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/test/java/org/json/simple/Test.java#L285), [2](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/parser/Yytoken.java#L11))を見ると、数値は(整数か小数かによらず)数値型として扱って欲しそう見えるので、 `Number` で扱うのがライブラリ作成者の意図に沿っているかもしれません。

```java
    private static int sum(JSONArray ja) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ja.size(); i++)
            sum += ((Number)ja.get(i)).intValue();
        return sum;
    }
```

(とはいえ、もはやこのライブラリが更新されることはないと思うので、今の実装に合わせてしまっても(つまり、整数が入力されることがわかっているのであれば`Long`にキャストしても)支障は無いと思いますが)