# json の少数整数混じりの配列の中身を java 言語上の double 型で取得したい

Tags: java

[json の int 配列の中身を java 言語上の int 型で取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/90993/json-%e3%81%ae-int-%e9%85%8d%e5%88%97%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%ad%e8%ba%ab%e3%82%92-java-%e8%a8%80%e8%aa%9e%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%ae-int-%e5%9e%8b%e3%81%a7%e5%8f%96%e5%be%97%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)
こちらで先程似た質問をしたんですが少数が含まれるケースをどう読めばいいかわからず困っています

少数がついていないのは Long になってしまって、
少数がついたものは Double になってしまうみたいなんですが、
キャストする前は Object 型でどちらの方に型にキャストできるか知る方法がありません
何かいい方法は有りませんか？

こちらがテストコードです

```
import java.io.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("test.json");
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject)parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
        JSONArray data = (JSONArray)json.get("data");
        System.out.println(sum(data));
    }

    private static double sum(JSONArray ja) {
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ja.size(); i++)
            sum += ((Double)ja.get(i)).doubleValue();
        return sum;
    }
}
```

以下のような少数混じりの JSON 配列を最終的に java 上に double で取得したいです

```
{
    "data": [1,1.5,2,2.5]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どういう入力が想定され、そこからどういう結果を得たいのかにもよりますが、差し当たって質問文中の入力を処理できるようにするには、 [`Number` 型](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html) として扱えばよいです。

```java
    private static double sum(JSONArray ja) {
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ja.size(); i++)
            sum += ((Number)ja.get(i)).doubleValue();
        return sum;
    }
```

利用されている JSON parser の実装を見ると、数値は [`Long`](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/parser/Yylex.java#L660) か [`Double`](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/parser/Yylex.java#L606) として扱われています。
`Number` はそれらに共通するスーパークラスです。

Comment: うまくいきました！　例外出してだめだったらもう片方にキャストするしか無いかなと思ってたんですがこんなクラスあるんですね。勉強になりました。